# Firebase notification don't work with all my app version

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I implemented Firebase Messaging in my swift app (1.2.1 version) following all google instructions, and all works perfectly. 
After I made a new version of the app (1.2.2), when I do this I copy paste the folder of my Xcode project and whit Apple generic versioning tool I set the new marketing version.
I uploaded 1.2.2 version on iTunes connect and my beta testers downloaded it.
Now when I send notifications only the devices whit 1.2.1 version recive it.
Have I to remake and reupload on firebase the push notifications certificate for every version of the app or I made some mistake?

(Sorry for my English, I'm an Italian guy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you change your bundle id?Or something have you deleted from your old source code?

Comment: So please check first.In your old source code, notifications are working or not.If notifications are working fine then copy your changes from your new project and put it in your old project.and then check.

Comment: Mistake found. For Sam reason in AppDelegate.swift there wasn't 'impor FirebaseMessaging'. Thanks for your support. That was a stupid error 